# What are the alternatives for meld (graphical diff tool) on OSX

Tags: svn, macos, diff, meld

I mostly develop on Linux and meld is indispensable for me. However, when I'm on the road I use a MacBook (leopard) and I want to use the same set of tools as on my main development box, meld being one of them.

Although you shoud be able to install meld, I could not succeed with it. So... are there any alternatives that are as good (or better) as meld?

One thing to point out, I use subversion and I just love the 'meld .' command that diffs my working directory to the BASE revision...

Johan

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10099/what-file-comparison-tool-can-i-use-under-os-x

Answer (score 42):

There's FileMerge.app, which comes with XCode.

It can be run as a separate standalone application :

[image]

Comment: To open it from the terminal, run `opendiff`.

Comment: usage: opendiff file1 file2 [-ancestor ancestorFile] [-merge mergeFile]

Comment: If you are used to the direct editing feature of `meld`, you will miss this at FileMerge

Comment: It seems a bit overkill that you need to install XCode for such a tool.

Comment: is there any app that lets you compare blank/unsaved files?

Answer (score 17):

**Apple's [FileMerge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Developer_Tools#FileMerge)** (which is included in their [Developer Tools download](http://developer.apple.com/tools/download/)) [looks similar to Meld](http://images.google.com/images?hl=en&q=apple+filemerge), though I confess to not having used either..

Comment: Note that FileMerge can be invoked from the command line as `opendiff`.

Answer (score 11):

[Sourcegear DiffMerge](http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/) is free and completely cross-platform (Windows, Mac and Linux).  I've only used the Windows version, and it lacks some more advanced features (like syntax highlighting and opening .diff files) but I'm very happy with it.

Comment: FYI, DiffMerge lacks line wrapping.

Answer (score 8):

[Fink](http://www.finkproject.org/) has a meld package.

Comment: Fink took a long time to build and installed about 50 packages, but eventually ran. Darwin ports did not.

Answer (score 7):

KDiff is cross platform, open source, and has an OSX binary available.

http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Changes.app](http://changesapp.com/).  Yes, it is for pay, but it's very capable, fast, easy on the eyes.  It also has a command line tool.  Take a look at the wiki for tips and tricks, especially with getting it to integrate with version control systems. I love Changes.app.

Comment: Since writing this I would now recommend [Kaleidoscope](http://www.kaleidoscopeapp.com) from Black Pixel. It can do text, directories, and images. I use it every day. It's one of the first things I install on a new dev Mac.

Answer (score 2):

[BBEdit](http://barebones.com/products/bbedit/) has a good diff viewer in it.

Answer (score 2):

Not a Mac user myself - but I stumbled across this post, and simultaneously found out about [tkdiff](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tkdiff/), whose screenshot seems to be taken on a Mac; so maybe it helps.. Cheers!